# Poor SQL performance after server transfer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, for-xml-explicit

We had a SQL 2005 server running for XML EXPLICIT queries quite happily with no performance issues. The machine (a Windows 2003 server) has unfortunately died so I've had to do an emergency provision of a Windows 2012 box. The databases files have been reattached to a 2008r2 and "work". However the queries are horrendously slow. 5 seconds per query when previously they were in the .x times. This makes the websites that they power unusable.
I've rebuilt all the indexes and I've run DBCC FREEPROCCACHE on all machines but this has had no noticable effect. What else can I look at ? I can't run them on the 2016 SQL instance on the box because some of the queries use non-ANSI *= joins (I said it was old!).

Comment: Looked at the query plan?

Comment: There may be many reasons, like all the DB statistics, result caches, and other data were lost, and has to be re-built. Do you see any slow improvement as the server is being used, or is it down now? It would be worth to start using it, and see if it is getting faster as these lost data are rebuilt again.

Comment: There is so very little to go on in the question, we can't possibly answer with at least an example of a query, the table definitions involved, the query plan etc. Also maybe there is contention on the server; what amount of memory does the server have versus what is really needed? Do you have slow disks maybe? A lot of concurrent requests and only one CPU? So many variables that you haven't highlighted.

Comment: Did you try updating the statistics (`EXEC sp_updatestats;`)?

Comment: Not tried updating statistics. Server is Windows 2016 vs Windows 2003, hex core 16gb ram vs something very old ! Much more modern and faster machine than previously. It's only being currently used by me to test so it's not load of concurrent users. Tried a few queries natively after capturing the SQL via SSP and running in SSMS and nothing immediate identified.
The physical database files were copied from the broken server and reattached to the new server. Not a backup/restore.

Answer (score 0):

If your query was running fine before, consider what else have changed - the query planner and actual execution plan might help to pinpoint this.

When you say you are joining, have you considered how much you join? If the new machine have more data in the database, then a join might quickly become prohibitively expensive. This can be done by reducing the data you need, as less datahandling means less workload.

Is there something you can pre-calculate before you run your query, or otherwise change to make it run faster?

I assume you do a SELECT, but if you UPDATE or DELETE data, the indexes also need to be recalculated, which takes a long time (in this case, disable the index, insert all the needed data and then recalculate the index)

You don't mention any XML handling, but have marked the for-xml tag. If your join is performed on XML data, using Xquery to get the data might also give a boost to performance.

Comment: If you have any additional info on you query or how it behaves, perhaps i can give some more specific advice :)

Comment: Why do you expect that there was a change in the amount of data? As I understand the same database files were attached to another server. So it should not a be simply a "general slow query", because previously it was fast with the same amount of data, same indexes, same XML handling.

Comment: Hi - no change to the amount of data - a straight copy of mdf & ldf files from the broken server to the new and reattach.
the "for xml explicit" to generate SQL output from the SP's. This is done using (what I no longer use) the TAG / parent type of generation with Unions to create the dataset and then order by. I'd not do it this way now ! No joins on XML data. There is already pre-calculation going on. I'll get one of the slow queries and try it on the SQL 2016 instance that's also available on the same. Need to find one that doens't have non-ANSI joins in as it will *NOT* work

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?
i'll happily help you, but at this point, i will probably need to see the code to help you :)